# Cannot get image from connection, even with INTERNET permissions

Tags: android, connection, socketexception, bitmapfactory

I'm having some problems trying to create a Bitmap from a remote URL. Here is the snippet:

```
    Bitmap bm = null;       

    URL aURL = null;
    try {
        aURL = new URL("http://developer.android.com/assets/images/home/honeycomb-android.png");                
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }

    if(aURL != null){
        URLConnection conn = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;             
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            is = conn.getInputStream();
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);                   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        } finally {
            if(bis != null){
                try {
                    bis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
            if(is != null){
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
            conn = null;
        }       
    }
```

I'm receiving an exception in the `conn.connect()` line.
 It says 
`java.net.SocketException: Permission denied`.

I've already added the permission in the manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0" package="mypackage.namehere">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>


        <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        </application>
    </manifest>
```

I can load the image both from my computer browser and the emulator browser. There's no firewall blocking my internet connection.
Tried with several URLs, but nothing worked.

Am I opening the connection correctly? Should I use HttpConnection instead?

Comment: do you comfortable with use of webview in which i can view this image if you res once me positive.

Comment: Shot in the dark: can you post your manifest?

Comment: @Otra here you are, edited above.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
Bitmap bm = null;       

URL aURL = null;
try {
    aURL = new URL("http://developer.android.com/assets/images/home/honeycomb-android.png");                
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    System.err.println(e);
}

if(aURL != null){
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;             
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) aURL.openConnection();
        is = conn.getInputStream();
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);                   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    } finally {
        if(bis != null){
            try {
                bis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
        if(is != null){
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
        conn = null;
    }       
}
```

Comment: This is strange. I've tested both my edited code AND your original code with no problems. The only thing I can possibly think of is that either you're behind a proxy or a firewall but you've already said that you have neither.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy easy, you are adding the permissions in the wrong place

```
...
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

after you close  can you see?

Comment: I don't see your point. In my AndroidManifest they are at the same level. I don't think adding before or after the <application> element does make any difference. In any case, they were added using the plugin manifest editor, so I think it should be fine.